# Rigorous proof of Frucht's theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory

I am looking for a nice and rigorous proof of Frucht's theorem (every (finite) group is isomorphic to a automorphism group of a (finite) graph).
So far, i have looked at the following:

[Combinatorial Problems and Exercises by Laszlo Lovasz](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821842625)

[Theory of graphs by Oystein Ore](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821810383)

[Frucht's original proof (in german)](http://www.numdam.org/article/CM_1939__6__239_0.pdf)

I was just wondering if someones knows of a nice(r) proof somewhere. I am not quite satisfied with the ones I looked at, I wish some things would be explained more elaborately and rigorously. Both english and german sources would be okay.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any restriction on the type of graph? That is, are we dealing only with simple (undirected) graphs or with directed graphs as well.

Comment: For example, if we allow directed multigraphs, this seems to have an extremely simple and elegant proof.

Comment: Also, have you seen this post? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331207/a-doubt-in-the-proof-of-fruchts-theorem?rq=1

Comment: I would prefer a version with simple graphs, and yes I have looked at this post. The post together with the book it references is my favourite. I was just hoping that maybe there is an even better version out there somewhere!